# How can I divide values from two different arrays which are not of the same length?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, charts, chart.js

I am trying to get DividendYield from a company for the last 20 years using ChartJs in laravel project. The arrays came from HTTP client API. The formula is like that :$dividendPayed / $dailyPrice * 100. The problem i am facing is that the $dividendPayed is once in three months so it makes that array shorter that the one which contains daily prices.

```
private function getDividend()
{
    $dividend = [];
    $response = Http::get('https://some-endpoint-for-once-in-3-months-dividend');
    $response->throw();
    foreach($response->json('historical') as $stock){
        $dividend [] = $stock['dividend'];
    }
    return $dividend;

   //THIS ARRAY RETURNS LET'S SAY FOR EXAMPLE 50 RESULTS
   // $dividend = [
    0 => 0.23
    1 => 0.23
    2 => 0.22
    3 => 0.22
    ..........
    50 => .43
                  ]


}

private function getPrice()
{
    $price = [];
    $response = Http::get('https://some-endpoint-for-daily-prices');
    $response->throw();
    foreach($response->json('historical') as $stockPrice){
        $price [] = $stockPrice['close'];
    }   
    return $price;
}

 //THIS ARRAY RETURNS LET'S SAY FOR EXAMPLE 240 RESULTS
   // $price = [
    0 => 147.27
    1 => 143.39
    2 => 143.86
    3 => 143.75
    4 => 142.41
    5 => 138.38
    ..........
    240 => 300.43
                  ]
```

I also have to mention that the 'date' in the chart for labels (day by day for the last 20 years) is taken from the same endpoint as $dailyPrice.

Comment: Not very clear... you can't divide array by array, so you'll have to iterate _both_ arrays and divide number by number. By that you would process all values from both arrays

Comment: just to get it straight, you are trying to get `$dividend / $price * 100`, like the total of `$dividend` / the total of `$price`?

Comment: Haven't i iterate trough that private functions? i have a foreach loop inside each one. What do you mean clearly? I need that the first dividend  0 => 0.23 to divide every daily price till 3 months, means that the next dividend will be divided with next 3 months daily prices, not the same prices, until it's time to came third dividend and so on. I need that dividend to be almost 3months in the equation, then next dividend.

Comment: @didenetahi No : let's have the example, first dividend is 0.23 and i need it to divide with the next (almost) 90 daily price, i mean 3 months. In the endpoint, every dividend has a date too, but it's 3 months apart from each other. So the next dividend i need to divide the next 90 daily prices and so on..

Comment: you need to divide each of `$dividend` element on precisely 90 element of `$price`, and stock each result in new `$result = array() ` so that the length of `$result` is 240 element, am i getting this straight?

Comment: Here is when it become scatchy, in the chart i need to be everyDayDividendYield form the last 20 years. $dividend (once in 3 months) / $price (daily) * 100. To understand let's say that in 1st Jan. 1990 the dividend it's 0.2, then i need that 0.2 to divide every daily prices that company has ( 1st jan: 55$, 2st Jan: 34$, 3rd Jan: 22$ ) till 1st Apr. 1990. The next dividend from st Apr. 1990 let's say 0.3 divide every daily prices that company has ( 1st Apr: 55$, 2st Apr: 34$, 3rd Apr: 22$ ) till 1st Jul. 1990.

Comment: @didenetahi For the question above, yes you are. In my code are data as examples, in reality that (almost) 90 days cames from API endpoint for the 3 months dividend and it looks like this
`  0 => array:7 [▼
    "date" => "2022-08-05"
    "label" => "August 05, 22"
    "dividend" => 0.23
    "recordDate" => "2022-08-08"
    "paymentDate" => "2022-08-11"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "date" => "2022-05-06"
    "label" => "May 06, 22"
    "dividend" => 0.23
    "recordDate" => "2022-05-09"
    "paymentDate" => "2022-05-12"
  ]`

Comment: @didenetahi kind of what you said ''you need to divide each of $dividend element on precisely 90 element of $price'' but with the dates came from the endpoints instead of '' precisely 90 ''

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention the full response from https://some-endpoint-for-once-in-3-months-dividend and  https://some-endpoint-for-daily-prices. Im assuming a date key exists with the responses for example

```
['historical'=>[['date'=>'2022-03-03','price'=>0.2]];
```

For fetching the API responses

```
private function fetchApiData(string $api,string $dateKey,string $priceKey,string $mainRespKey='historical'){
   $data = [];
   $response = Http::get($api);
   $response->throw();
   return $response->json($mainRespKey);}
```

For calculating the DividendYield

```
public function DividendYield(){
   $dividend   = $this->fetchApiData('https://some-endpoint-for-once-in-3-months-dividend','date','dividend');

   $dailyPrice = $this->fetchApiData('https://some-endpoint-for-daily-prices','date','price');

   if(!empty($dividend)){
       $dividendColl  = collect($dividend);
       return collect($dailyPrice)->whereIn('date',$dividendColl->pluck('date'))
                                         ->map(fn($price)=>$dividendColl->where('date',$price['date'])
                                                                        ->map(fn($dividend)=> ['date'=>$price['date'],
                                                                                               'DividendYield'=>(($dividend['dividend']/$price['price'])*100)]))->collapse();     
   }}
```

Comment: I did not because i thought it's not legal on this site.
Daily price 
- https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/AAPL?serietype=line&apikey=9d356e0853e8c35e63893849ce5c2de5

Divdends (3 months) - 
https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/stock_dividend/AAPL?apikey=9d356e0853e8c35e63893849ce5c2de5

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to group your `$price` by month, assuming that the `dd()` in your comment is what `price`is, by using:

```
$price = collect($price)->groupBy(function($val) {
      return Carbon::parse($val->date)->format('m');
});
```

then you need to loop through the `$dividend`:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($dividend as $key => $value) {
    $mounthResult = array();
    foreach ($price[key] as $p) {
// assuming dividend is the price you mean
        array_push($mounthResult, $value/$p->dividend*100);
    }
    array_push($result, $temp);
}
```

The `$price[key]` means the month group we want, so if `key = 0` that means we are looping the first month.

I hope i get you right, feel free to comment on this to help me understand you more if i'm wrong.

Comment: I will try both, first of all as i said, i'm working with charts.js, first thing i need to fetch labels as everyDay. Then i need to store based on daily prices and dividend the dividendYield to fetch the labels (simple date with carbon). Thank you all, i posted the API endpoints for both. Labels i am getting form the endpoint where is also the daily price value, there are arrays with only 2 keys. I did not post the endpoints cause i thought i will be banned for adding ads.

Comment: You should have written a specific example of your api output, rather than shorten it into one element.